# Car Security System Problem

Tags: security, alarm, fuse-panel

I have problems with the security system of my car.

If I press the LOCK button in the key fob, there were sound indicators but the door locks are still unlocked. When I tried to open the door, the alarm will go off. I need to press the UNLOCK button to turn off the alarm.

If I press the UNLOCK button in the key fob, it will lock the doors. Of course I could not open the doors, so I need to manually unlock the doors using the key.

Right now, I use some method to lock and unlock the car.
To unlock:

1. Press the unlock button in the key fob.
2. Use the car keys to manually unlock the doors.

To lock:

1. Manually lock the doors using the car keys
2. Press the lock button in the key fob.
3. Make sure the all the doors are locked.

I tried searching in the internet, because I want to disable the alarm (to save the car's battery). I checked that I could pull the fuse for the alarm.

Questions:

1. What are the possible causes of this problem?
2. Will pulling out the fuse solve the problem?

Comment: When was the battery in the fob last replaced? Also could you tell us what car this is? And its year?

Comment: If you are OK with possibly loosing the lock/unlock functionality of  the fob and there is nothing else on the alarm system fuse, then yes, pulling the fuse might do the trick, but there may be other systems served by the same fuse.

Comment: @dlu I have no idea when it was last replaced. But I tried using 2 fobs (other one is backup). Ford Lynx GSi 2002. I do not know if the security system is built-in or added later.